# Visual Studio 2010/2008 Error: An Invalid Argument Was Supplied

Tags: visual-studio-2010

All of a sudden I am unable to run any web application in Visual Studio 2010. I get an error message (shown in the image below. I get the same message when I try to run or issue the View in browser or Browse With command.

The project compiles properly and then I get this error message.

I am able to run WinForms applications normally.

I have uninstalled all the extensions from visual studio 2010 still I am getting this error.

[image: An invalid argument was supplied]

Please advice how can I find out what is causing this problem.

**Update 1:**
I get the same error in Visual Studio 2008 also.
I tried logging using the devenv /Log switch, but it doesn't show any errors or warnings.

Comment: Have you had a look at the properties of your web project - see what is set in the start up tab?

Comment: The Default.aspx page is set as the start page. Even if I change those options, I still get the same error.

I have also tried resetting my visual studio 2010 settings to no avail.

Comment: I face the same problem with VS 2008. Currently I am repairing VS to see if that fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, but did not find a way to fix it.

The problem was Visual Studio was unable to launch the Default Web Server. My system is under a domain. The firewall settings are maintained by the group policy. Somehow it got reset to default. After which I was not able to download files using Internet Download Manager or launch the Visual Studio webserver.

I did a system restore and everything started working.

Please close this thread.

Comment: When I try to accept my own answer. It says "You can accept your own answer in <time> hours".
But the answer never gets accepted :(